# Oauth Client Creation Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api, twitter, oauth

I'm working with rails to create a client for the Fitbit API (very similar to twitter api) on Rails.

In my device.rb file

```
  def fitbit_data
    @client = Fitgem::Client.new (
      :consumer_key => 'bb1', #I understand the security issues here and will change it for production
      :consumer_secret => '81f',
      :token => oauth_token,
      :secret => oauth_token_secret,
     :user_id => uid
    )
  end
```

It says that my syntax is wrong and asks for a ')' after :consumer_key. How do I get the syntax correct?

Comment: Take a look at the source code at `initialize` method (there's an example there at line 88) https://github.com/whazzmaster/fitgem/blob/master/lib/fitgem/client.rb

Comment: ya, I'm changed it to follow that exactly, but I'm still getting syntax errors. Where should this be located? (device.rb or device_controller.rb)?

Answer (score 0):

Note: this answer is applicable for Rails 4.1.4 and Fitgem 0.10.0.

I think the issue here is that to initialize a client, you have to pass in a hash. Additionally, I do not believe it's necessary to specify a user_id key. See my code below:

```
$client = Fitgem::Client.new ({ :consumer_key => ENV["FITBIT_CONSUMER_KEY"], 
                            :consumer_secret => ENV["FITBIT_CONSUMER_SECRET"],
                            :token => ENV["OAUTH_TOKEN"],
                            :secret => ENV["OAUTH_SECRET"] })
```

Let me know if this helps.